# Can't get user photo with graph.microsoft.com

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm new to OpenId Connect authentication and graph.microsoft.com and am having problem getting user's photo.

I have a website built with ASP.NET Web Forms and am replacing Microsoft authentication to OpenId because it has deprecated.

So, I've added an app at the Azure portal and the authentication is working fine. I've managed to get access token from the authentication, but am struggling to get user's photo using graph.microsoft.com.

The app at Azure has User.Read permission (Delegated permission).

I've set the header to include Authorization and Bearer [access_token] as key and value and the GET request is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/suencien@hotmail.com/photo/$value

suencien@hotmail.com is the authenticated email address.

The response I get is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnableToReadToken",
    "message": "OAuth token submitted with the request can not be parsed.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "880a2e95-5e47-4b74-9ff5-c5f4e9a9feed",
      "date": "2020-04-16T10:47:11"
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect it's not a valid access token, or there might be a setting at Azure I missed, or is it simply not supported?

The access_token retuned from OpenID Connect was

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6ImhGR252WFNUSjlKcXRDWDgtTUNOclkzZDFWdzN3cDJlSFdBX2ZoN2tzeXMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSIsImtpZCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSJ9.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.Y7lgr0b7Z286Sh3xv8_KQ-_cGYPnzHES0a3871FWNPSoTu1GDSuLj6ItV-jp9959gumKGHEnYDqBC1GsQnv5xq8er6hqT3PCiVQu8-1FE5u54HkTcFayPrg9n4db2mhCTflJr_q5wSKkKBAOF0d7q55-pskNLjBuN-LVFguIRDgp-IBFFfPzptk6SFvj_pkjk4dAVFyNvijcpGkIZ_43DW2Si1IeU_7ek-D9K9wr_PBj_hqKJrOc0lgYcrq0TsuM55F1-MOVjpWmsvU46BM0L7ESSBOIkbpcBkD7fOroW3DjgvHs6xUhEc-xjqNcFvkdw1HUr76MHzOTy6gUlXKheg

Could someone please help me or direct me to the right path? :)

Comment: Firstly, it seems that there are no permissions in the access token. You can decode it in https://jwt.ms. But the error message is not related to permissions. It means your access token is not put into the header correctly. Besides, I notice that you are using Microsoft Graph to query photo of a personal account. It's not supported currently. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions.

Comment: The access token is already at the header. Yeah I read that too. So it's not supported then. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll post an answer about the information we discussed above. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion, Delegated (personal Microsoft account) is not supported to [Get photo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions).

[image]

You are trying to get the photo of a personal Microsoft account. So I'm afraid that it can't be implemented.